# Not always seeing print statements when calling python from bash

Tags: bash, python3

Using something like this:

```
rtncod=`./FetchTemps.py`
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "bad news in FetchTemps" > ./Fetch_Temps.err
fi
```

I never see any print statements in from my python script. Instead I get a message such as "command substitution, ignored null byte" or something like that.  The messages are being ate up so I then changed my python script from

```
except BaseException as e:
       print("conn.send failed:" + str(e)
```

to use

```
       logger.error("conn.send failed:" + str(e)
```

I no longer get those messages about the null byte but where do I look for the logger error messages?  Sorry, I am a newbie on python.  I do know that the =`.'" is what eats up the messages as when I run the python without the assignment messages get printed.  Maybe I don't need to the rtrcod= mechansism?  What does $? hold? is it the 'e' from the exception?

Comment: I think what you really mean to ask is how to get python to return a non-zero error code?

Comment: I have not set up the logger.  There is more to do than just putting in a logger.errror line of code.  I need to read up on how to use the logger. I thought it would just go to syslog automatically

Comment: Does your code have the close `)` to match the open one after `print(` ?  i.e. `print("conn.send failed:" + str(e))`